# Is it possible to set tested class' method's return value in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Say, there's the following class to be tested:

```
public class MyClass {
     public void method1() {
          ... 
          String str = method3()
          ...
     }
     public int method2() {...}
     private String method3() {...}
}
```

I'm writing `MyClassTest.java` with JUnit. I want `method3()` to return a value that I have assigned, not execute the method itself. I can only use Mockito.

Is it possible?

If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: it is possible. `MyClass myMock = mock(MyClass.class); when(myMock.method3()).thenReturn("it's alive!");`

Comment: @diginoise This won't work - `method3` is private within `MyClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just Mockito you cannot mock a private method.
But you could refactor your code to extract `method3()` in another class as a public method that you could use as dependency of `MyClass`. In this way `method3()` is naturally mockable.

```
public class MyClass {

     private Foo foo;
     public MyClass(Foo foo){
        this.foo = foo;
     }
     public void method1() {
          ... 
          String str = foo.method3()
          ...
     }
     public int method2() {...}
}
public class Foo {
     public String method3() {...}
}
```

Now mock that in the unit test :

```
@Mock
Foo fooMock;
MyClass myClass;

@BeforeEach
void init(){
    myClass = new MyClass(fooMock);
}

@Test
public void method1(){
   Mockito.when(fooMock.method3()).thenReturn("dummy value");
   // call method1() 
   // do assertions
}
```

Comment: And proud of ! The cut was short !  I procrastinate too much on SO !  After eating I cut, at least I will try LOL

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with **Mockito**, but you can with [JMockit](http://jmockit.github.io/index.html). Your test would look like this:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class JMockitTest {

    @Tested
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        myClass = new MyClass();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1(){

        new MockUp<MyClass>() {

            @Mock
            String method3() {
                return "dummy value";
            }
        };

        myClass.method1();

        // do assertions
    }
}
```

You can read the documentation about this feature, called faking, [here](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Faking.html).